# WriteConsoleOutput();関数で半角スペースを開けて文字が描画される原因が知りたい。

Tags: c++

`setDraw();`関数ですがなぜ半角スペースを開けて描画されるのでしょうか？引数で文字を"MENU"として入力してその後それを`mScreenBuffer`に値を設定しているのですが何がおかしいのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
#include "DrawCharactor.hpp"

// コンストラクタ
DrawCharactor::DrawCharactor()
{
    fopen_s(&fp,"Log.txt","w"); //ファイル

    
    //描画開始座標
    mDraw_start.X = 0;
    mDraw_start.Y = 0;

    //描画範囲
    mDraw_size.X = MAX_WIDTH;
    mDraw_size.Y = MAX_HEIGHT;

    //ウインドウサイズ
    mRect.Left = (SHORT)0;
    mRect.Top = (SHORT)0;
    mRect.Right = (SHORT)MAX_WIDTH;
    mRect.Bottom = (SHORT)MAX_HEIGHT;

    // バッファーを作成
    mHandle = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);

    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(mHandle);  //有効にする

    if (mHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    { 
        fprintf(fp, "Invalid: INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE \n"); 
    }

    // 画面バッファサイス変更
    if (SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(mHandle, mDraw_size) == 0) 
    { 
        fprintf(fp,"Invalid: SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(); \n"); 
    }

    // 画面サイズ変更
    if (SetConsoleWindowInfo(mHandle, TRUE, &mRect) != 0) 
    { 
        fprintf(fp, "Invalid: SetConsoleWindowInfo(); \n"); 
    }    

}

// バッファーに文字を書き込む
void DrawCharactor::setDraw(const char* format, ...)
{    
    
    va_list ap;
    char str[MAX_WIDTH];
    va_start(ap, format);
    vsprintf_s(str, sizeof(str), format, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    wchar_t wc[MAX_WIDTH];
    size_t size = sizeof(wc);

    size_t count = sizeof(wc) / sizeof(wchar_t);
    mbstowcs_s(&size, wc, count, str, count - 1);   //マルチ文字をワイド文字に変換

//    printf("%zu: [%ls]\n", size, wc);
//    printf("%zu: [%lc]\n", size, wc[0]);

    fprintf(fp,"%lc\n",wc[1]);



    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int  i = 0;
    for (; mNowBuffer_width[mNowBuffer_height] <= MAX_WIDTH; mNowBuffer_width[mNowBuffer_height]++) {

        if (wc[i] != L'\0') {

            if (mNowBuffer_width[mNowBuffer_height] <= MAX_WIDTH) {
                mScreenBuffer[mNowBuffer_height][mNowBuffer_width[mNowBuffer_height]].Char.UnicodeChar = wc[i];
                mScreenBuffer[mNowBuffer_height][mNowBuffer_width[mNowBuffer_height]].Attributes = FOREGROUND_GREEN;
                mNowBuffer_width[mNowBuffer_height]++;

            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(fp,"一行の文字数を超えています。\n");
            }
            i++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //fprintf(fp, "ああああ\n");
}

// 描画
void DrawCharactor::GenerateOutput()
{
    WriteConsoleOutput(mHandle,mScreenBuffer[0], mDraw_size, mDraw_start, &mRect); //現在のカーソル位置から始まる文字列をコンソール画面バッファーに書き込み   
    mNowBuffer_height = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        mNowBuffer_width[i] = 0;
    }
    
}

//　デストラクタ
DrawCharactor::~DrawCharactor()
{
    // スクリーンバッファを解放
    CloseHandle(mHandle);
    mHandle = NULL;

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

提示コードの `mNowBuffer_width[mNowBuffer_height]++;`が不要でした。自己解決です。